# Identify plant (tree)

Tags: identification

I brought this plant from a local nursery (Jaipur, India), I put this in a big pot few weeks ago but this is growing really fast. I brought this of around 3 feet and now its around 6 feet. I would like to know name of this plant (looks like a tree now). If anybody know "hindi" name of this plant that would be great. [image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you most certainly have either a [Ceiba](https://www.google.ca/search?q=ceiba%20leaves&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=960&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjuztSco-fPAhXDRSYKHWXYD18Q_AUIBigB) or [Bombax](https://www.google.ca/search?q=ceiba%20leaves&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=960&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjuztSco-fPAhXDRSYKHWXYD18Q_AUIBigB#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=bombax%20leaves) here. The leaves of several species of both genera are very similar and would most likely require a flower for positive ID.

**Hindi Common names:**

Bombax - शाल्मली Shalmali, सेमल Semal

Ceiba - Safed semal सफ़ेद सेमल

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a beautiful specimen of the Indian Horsechestnut. Kanor and Bankhor are listed as the Hindi names, and you should be able to confirm that.

Word to the wise, this is a tree, and appears to grow spectacular in size. I don't think it is going to be happy in the pot for long!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% on this, but the first thing that came to mind when I saw it was a Schefflera or Umbrella tree.  It also resembles a vitex/chaste tree.